# How do I install a device driver provided as a .bin file?

Tags: linux, drivers, arm, angstrom

I am a new Linux user and am struggling installing a driver for a usb WiFi device I want to use on an embedded system (BeagleBone).

When I download the driver for the chipset (Ralink 2070), it is provided as a bin file. I have tried making it executable (`chmod +x`), but using `file` says it is a data file and I cannot execute.

How do I use this bin file to install the chipset driver? Do I only need to place this in a folder, and if so, where should it be placed?

Comment: Where did you get this driver?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! The compatibility page I downloaded the driver from listed the bin as a driver, but modprobe proved it a firmware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect what you have is a firmware, rather than a driver. Try placing it in `/usr/lib/firmware`. I believe the driver for that device is `rt2800usb`, so after the firmware is in place, run `modprobe rt2800usb`. If modprobe complains about not finding the driver, you'll have to compile it, and that deserves a separate question.

Comment: Thanks shawn for the reply! I tried placing that file in the folder and ran modprobe. The message returned said that the bin was not found, so it looks like it is indeed firmware. I will try compiling and submit another question if need. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If `file` says it's a data file (as opposed to an executable file), something looks quite wrong here: maybe the file is a firmware rather than a driver?

Comment: `file` would identify it as an x86 executable if that were the case.

Comment: I see. Edited my answer to remove that.